# Accessing onRequestPermissionsResult event from an Activity instance (Capacitor Plugin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, permissions, capacitor

I have a Capacitor Plugin that includes an Android Library. Within this library, I'm using the requestPermissions function from the ActivityCompat class. In order to react when the user makes a selection (grants or denies permission), I need access to the onRequestPermissionsResult event. However, I can only access it from the Activity. Although I can obtain the current instance of the Activity using the Capacitor Plugin package, I cannot access the class itself and therefore cannot override the onRequestPermissionsResult method to react accordingly.

Is there any way to achieve this, as I need to execute my code only after the user has responded to the permission request? Alternatively, is there a way to get the status of the request using the requestCode?